# What is the 'missing' parameter doing in statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf, statistically speaking?

Tags: python, statsmodels, autocorrelation

I am using the acf function to calculate the autocorrelation provided by statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf. One of the parameters is called *missing* and can take the values ‘none’, ‘raise’, ‘conservative’, and ‘drop’, which change how the function handles NaN values. The problem is, I can't find any documetation on *how* exactly what each of these values change the statistics that are being done.

I am working with an evenly spaced time series, which has a scattering of missing values and a large gap of missing measurements in the middle. My solution thus far has been to subtract the median from the time series to center it around zero and then insert 0 in all the missing values. Does one of these parameter values do a similar thing, and should I be handling things differently?

Comment: Please update what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

'none' does nothing to the NANs, 'raise' raises an error in case the data contains NANs.

```
MissingDataError("NaNs were encountered in the data")
```

'drop' removes the NANs from the code before calculation is proceeded and, as far as I understand the source code (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html), the option 'conservative' replaces all NANs by 0.

```
    missing = missing.lower()
if missing not in ['none', 'raise', 'conservative', 'drop']:
    raise ValueError("missing option %s not understood" % missing)
if missing == 'none':
    deal_with_masked = False
else:
    deal_with_masked = has_missing(x)
if deal_with_masked:
    if missing == 'raise':
        raise MissingDataError("NaNs were encountered in the data")
    notmask_bool = ~np.isnan(x)  # bool
    if missing == 'conservative':
        # Must copy for thread safety
        x = x.copy()
        x[~notmask_bool] = 0
    else:  # 'drop'
        x = x[notmask_bool]  # copies non-missing
    notmask_int = notmask_bool.astype(int)  # int
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems consistent with what I see when manually dropping NANs or replacing them with zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is detailed in the ACF function docstring [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html)

> missing: str, default “none”
> A string in [“none”, “raise”, “conservative”, “drop”] specifying how the NaNs are to be treated. “none” performs no checks. “raise” raises an exception if NaN values are found. “drop” removes the missing observations and then estimates the autocovariances treating the non-missing as contiguous. “conservative” computes the autocovariance using nan-ops so that nans are removed when computing the mean and cross-products that are used to estimate the autocovariance. When using “conservative”, n is set to the number of non-missing observations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).